# Wdio test run into gitlab CI has connection Issue

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, webdriver-io

I am trying to run wdio test into gitlab ci. I am using wdio versio 7 and node version 18
But I am facing issue.

**My Gitlab Job looks like this**

```
statistics-test-prod:
  stage: e2e_test
  services:
    - selenium/standalone-chrome
  script:
    - npm i && browser=chrome browserInstance=3 npm run test --host=selenium__standalone-chrome
```

**package.json dependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
        "-": "^0.0.1",
        "allure-commandline": "^2.18.1",
        "axios": "^1.2.5",
        "csv-stringify": "^6.2.0",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
        "lorem-ipsum": "^2.0.8",
        "save-dev": "^0.0.1-security",
        "ssl-root-cas": "^1.3.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^7.23.0",
        "@wdio/browserstack-service": "^7.25.2",
        "@wdio/cli": "^7.20.1",
        "@wdio/jasmine-framework": "^7.20.0",
        "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.34.0",
        "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^7.33.0",
        "@wdio/shared-store-service": "^7.20.2",
        "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.20.0",
        "chromedriver": "^120.0.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.8.1",
        "typescript": "^4.7.3",
        "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.3.2"
    }
```

**Error I get after running the job**

```
Execution of 1 workers started at 2024-01-26T14:09:13.441Z
[0-1] RUNNING in chrome - /test/specs/statisticsCreation.spec.ts
[0-1] 2024-01-26T14:09:40.163Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:40821
[0-1]     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16)
[0-1] FAILED in chrome - /test/specs/statisticsCreationForDE02.spec.ts
Spec Files:  0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:26 
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:03
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I expect test should run into gitlab ci